# How to add a null-safe dereference operator and return null instead of executing the method

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, nullreferenceexception, expression-trees

I write an assembly during runtime, which stores me all getter methods for all properties from about 1000 types.

The code I use to pull the getters is as follows:

```
public static void CreateGetter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    if (propertyInfo.DeclaringType == null || propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)
    {
        propertyGetters.Add(propertyInfo, null);
        return;
    }

    Func<object, object> compiledGetterLambda = null;

    try
    {
        // Instance parameter, passed as input as object
        ParameterExpression objectParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "instance");

        // Cast instance to the actual type
        UnaryExpression instanceExpression = Expression.TypeAs(objectParameterExpression, propertyInfo.DeclaringType);

        // Call the getter and retrieve the value
        MemberExpression propertyValueExpression = Expression.Property(instanceExpression, propertyInfo);

        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(SomeClass))
        {
            instanceExpression = Expression.TypeAs(propertyValueExpression, typeof(SomeClass));

            propertyValueExpression = Expression.Property(instanceExpression, nameof(SomeClass.Id));
        }

        // Convert the value to object
        UnaryExpression propertyValueObjectExpression = Expression.Convert(propertyValueExpression, typeof(object));

        // Create lambda
        Expression<Func<object, object>> getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(propertyValueObjectExpression, objectParameterExpression);

        rawPropertyGetters.Add(propertyInfo, getterLambda);

        // Compile lambda
        compiledGetterLambda = getterLambda.Compile();
    }
    catch
    {
        // ignored
    }

    propertyGetters.Add(propertyInfo, compiledGetterLambda);
}
```

This is an example of a resulting code:

```
public static object getValue_SomeClass(object instance)
{
    return ((instance as BaseClass).get_SomeClass() as SomeClass).get_Id();
}
```

The problem now is that this is not null-safe. For example, it may be that (instance as BaseClass).get_SomeClass() returns null. If I then further cast this with "as SomeClass" and call "get_Id()", an exception is of course thrown.

To avoid this, the resulting code should look like this:

```
public static object getValue_SomeClass(object instance)
{
    return ((instance as BaseClass)?.get_SomeClass() as SomeClass)?.get_Id() ?? null;
}
```

Can someone help me with that or lead me to the right direction to achieve the desired result?

It's also ok, if I have to save the value in a parameter and use "if" to check if it's null, if that is simpler to accomplish.

Comment: what's wrong with what you have in that last `getValue_SomeClass` function?

Comment: In the last getValue_SomeClass I added the "?" before the method calls and "?? null" at the end. This is the desired result. But so far, I'm only getting the above getValue_SomeClass.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with the following:

```
public static void CreateGetter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    if (propertyInfo.DeclaringType == null || propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)
    {
        propertyGetters.Add(propertyInfo, null);
        return;
    }

    Func<object, object> compiledGetterLambda = null;

    try
    {
        // Instance parameter, passed as input as object
        ParameterExpression objectParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "instance");

        TypeBinaryExpression typeIsDeclaringTypeExpression = Expression.TypeIs(objectParameterExpression, propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
        ConstantExpression nullValueExpression = Expression.Constant(null);

        ConditionalExpression conditionalExpression = Expression.Condition(
            typeIsDeclaringTypeExpression,
            Expression.Convert(
                Expression.Property(
                    Expression.Convert(objectParameterExpression, propertyInfo.DeclaringType),
                    propertyInfo),
                typeof(object)),
            nullValueExpression);

        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetProperty("Id") != null)
        {
            conditionalExpression = Expression.Condition(
                Expression.Equal(conditionalExpression, Expression.Constant(null)),
                conditionalExpression,
                Expression.Convert(
                    Expression.Property(
                        Expression.Convert(
                            conditionalExpression, propertyInfo.PropertyType),
                        "Id"),
                    typeof(object))
                );
        }

        // Create lambda
        Expression<Func<object, object>> getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(conditionalExpression, objectParameterExpression);

        rawPropertyGetters.Add(propertyInfo, getterLambda);

        // Compile lambda
        compiledGetterLambda = getterLambda.Compile();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // ignored
    }

    propertyGetters.Add(propertyInfo, compiledGetterLambda);
}
```

For those who don't know:
Expression trees don't support the null-coalescing operator.
For further limitation, search on the following page for "limitations", there are quite a few!
https://tyrrrz.me/blog/expression-trees